# Regexp newline in replacements

Tags: php, regex, replace, newline

I need to replace all spaces with newline, but when I wrote `\n` as a replacement, it changed just into `\n` as a text.

How can I fix it? I spent a lot of time looking for this in the internet, but I was not successful.

Comment: In what environment are you executing the regular expression?

Comment: hey :) it is php preg_replace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$str = 'this is my string';
$str = preg_replace('/\s/', "\n", $str);
var_dump($str);
```

The `\n` needs to be wrapped in double quote so that it is interpolated as a newline character.

Also, if you are doing this for HTML output, you won't see a difference.  You'll need to replace the whitespace with `<br/>` instead:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s/', '<br/>', $str);
```